# How can I access Windows 7 files/folders from Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, samba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why I can't access partition on which I have installed it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20535/why-i-cant-access-partition-on-which-i-have-installed-it)

I installed **Samba** but I could not get it working.

Is there another program or way to access them?

Can you please direct me to a online tutorial or write one?

Comment: In a dual-boot scenario (windows is local) or over the network?

Comment: @Christopher Local. I am **dual-boot**. Using WUBI.